# Material UI AutoComplete component size behavior

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete, uisearchbar

I want autocomplete(for me it's a search bar) component to stay in one line and expand when searching. Sadly, the component adds another line when there is a long chip.
For example:
[the image shows that the component added a line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcjhq.png)

how can I stop the component from adding a new line while maintaining it's behavior while writing in it (when you write in the component it expands to show the entire search)

I tried changing its CSS a max lines prop but it didn't work.
granted I might missed something in the CSS

To summarize the behavior of the bar:
it is a multi select
There are two situations

1. the user isn't using it.
   In that situation the bar should just be one line nothing more
2. the user clicked on it and editing in the bar
   In that situation the bar should expand vertically to and show all the chips

right now It correspond with the situation that I described, but if a chip that is too big it expands to two lines and I want it to stay just one line if it isn't situation 2.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't give you my code or photos from what i'm working on. I am not allowed to

Comment: Is the autocomplete also a multiselect? If I understand, you don't want new lines, you just want the bar to continuously expand horizontally? What you can do is make a codesandbox with an example of what you have tried already

Comment: I added what you asked to the question under summarize of the bar's behavior

Comment: So it just keeps expanding horizontally forever and never breaks line? Or like this at 100% with items inside it : https://hgy57u.csb.app/

Comment: I will correct my self it should expand vertically.
right now It correspond with the situation that I described, but if a chip that is too big it expands to two lines